# Modal view being displaced

Tags: iphone

I have the following code to show a modal view which is added as a subview of my tabBarController. However despite using the autoresizingMask property to allow for when an incoming cellular call interrupts my app and shows the green status bar at the top, i find after this event the whole view is displaced by 20 pixels downwards

```
    - (void) showLogin:(UIView*) modalView
   {
     CGPoint middleCenter = CGPointMake(160, 226);
     CGSize offSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
     CGPoint offScreenCenter = CGPointMake(offSize.width / 2.0, -210); // start from top
     modalView.center = offScreenCenter; // we start off-screen
         modalView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:modalView];

    // Show it with a transition effect
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4]; // animation duration in seconds
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    modalView.center = middleCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
   }
```

How to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Clarification: When you say, "the whole view is displaced" do you mean the modalView or the tabBarController.view.

Comment: I have a similar problem with a modal when it comes back from a fullscreen video.

Comment: Sorry its the modal view that is displaced by the height of the green bar downwards.

Comment: You could try setting the mask to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin` instead of just the top margin. That might make it fill up those 20 pixels when the status bar goes back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this a simulator vs. device issue?

On the simulator, the bar simply appears. But that's never going to happen on a real device.

You're never going to just get a green bar on the top of a real device. Instead, your app will go away. When your app "returns," the view will be entirely rebuilt.

Comment: No , this will never happen on the Simulator its the bar you get when you get a cellular call and then switch to another app from the inbuilt phone app whilst the call is still active

Comment: Just to clarify its the bar that has 'Touch to return to call'

Comment: Yeah, that's the bar I mean. On a real device, it'll never just appear. You'll be sent to the background, and when you're brought back to the foreground your view gets laid out again. If it isn't resizing properly, your resize properties are wrong. See Responding to Interruptions here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html

Comment: BTW, you can get this on the simulator... Menu->Hardware->Toggle in call status bar.

Comment: The bar does just appear when tethering sometimes, at least it's theoretically possible if you were to turn tethering on, then go back to the app, then connect a computer.  Also, while it can't just appear for a phone call, it does disappear without sending the app to the background if the other party hangs up.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just present a modal view controller on top of the bar bar?

Of course, you'd have to wrap your modalView into a view controller, but that should not be a problem.

```
[self.tabBarController.view presentModalViewController: ... animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override `-(void)layoutSubviews` in `self.tabBarController.view`, check the new bounds of that view, and reposition the login view by hand as the bounds change.